# Python dictionary issue when fetching value

Tags: python

I have a csv file to capture the data in my python script. The sample data is given below:

```
Project_Key,URL,Ticket_Number
Guna:Test-00:Project_1,https://refernce.org.net/group/sub-group/repo-name-1,ABC12345
Guna:Test-01:Project_1,https://refernce.org.net/group/subgroup/repo-name-1,ABC12346
Guna:Test-00:Project_2,https://refernce.org.net/group/sub-group/repo-name-2,ABC12347
```

I capture the data from the csv file and allocate them into separate dictionaries in python. When I print them, the data of the dictionaries were incorrect. Not sure what went wrong. I tried in Python v.3.10.2 and v.3.11.5. I am facing same issue in both versions. Could anyone please help on fixing this?

Python script:

```
import sys
import os
import csv

def capture_csv_data():
    try:
        input_list=[]
        with open("C:\\Personal\\Learning\\python\\request-data.csv") as csv_file:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(reader)
            for row_element in reader:
                input_list.append(row_element)
        csv_file.close()
        process_csv_data(input_list)
    except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:
        print("\n Exception at capture_csv_data: ")
        print(e)

def process_csv_data(input_list):
    try:
        dict_pkey = dict_url = dict_ticket = {}
        pkee = repo_url = ticket_number = ""
        for input_item in input_list:
            list_elements = list(input_item)
            pkee = str(list_elements[0])
            repo_url = str(list_elements[1])
            ticket_number = str(list_elements[2])
            print("Key: " + pkee + " - URL: " + repo_url + " - ticket: " + ticket_number)
            dict_pkey[pkee] = pkee
            dict_url[pkee] = repo_url
            dict_ticket[pkee] = ticket_number
        print(dict_pkey)
        print(dict_url)
        print(dict_ticket)
    except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:
        print("\n Exception at process_csv_data: ")
        print(e)

def main():
    capture_csv_data()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Expected Output:**

> {'Guna:Test-00:Project_1': 'Guna:Test-00:Project_1',
> 'Guna:Test-01:Project_1': 'Guna:Test-01:Project_1',
> 'Guna:Test-00:Project_2': 'Guna:Test-00:Project_2'}
> {'Guna:Test-00:Project_1':
> 'https://refernce.org.net/group/sub-group/repo-name-1',
> 'Guna:Test-01:Project_1':
> 'https://refernce.org.net/group/subgroup/repo-name-1',
> 'Guna:Test-00:Project_2':
> 'https://refernce.org.net/group/sub-group/repo-name-2'}
> {'Guna:Test-00:Project_1': 'ABC12345', 'Guna:Test-01:Project_1':
> 'ABC12346', 'Guna:Test-00:Project_2': 'ABC12347'}

**Actual Output:**

> Key: Guna:Test-00:Project_1 - URL: https://refernce.org.net/group/sub-group/repo-name-1 - ticket: ABC12345
> Key: Guna:Test-01:Project_1 - URL: https://refernce.org.net/group/subgroup/repo-name-1 - ticket: ABC12346
> Key: Guna:Test-00:Project_2 - URL: https://refernce.org.net/group/sub-group/repo-name-2 - ticket: ABC12347
> {'Guna:Test-00:Project_1': 'ABC12345', 'Guna:Test-01:Project_1': 'ABC12346', 'Guna:Test-00:Project_2': 'ABC12347'}
> {'Guna:Test-00:Project_1': 'ABC12345', 'Guna:Test-01:Project_1': 'ABC12346', 'Guna:Test-00:Project_2': 'ABC12347'}
> {'Guna:Test-00:Project_1': 'ABC12345', 'Guna:Test-01:Project_1': 'ABC12346', 'Guna:Test-00:Project_2': 'ABC12347'}

Comment: `dict_pkey = dict_url = dict_ticket = {}`: **All** three variables point to the **same dictionary** - is that what you want? Use `dict_pkey = {}; dict_url = {}; dict_ticket = {}` instead and look what happens.

Comment: +1 for what @Timus has said. Also, you could try another approach using [pandas to read the CSV for you](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thank you @Timus. It worked. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Sure @RafaeldeBem. I will give a try

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize dicts separately:

```
dict_pkey = {}
dict_url = {}
dict_ticket = {}
```

Here works fine!

Comment: Thank you @Giba. It worked. I was in an assumption that I am declaring multiple variables in a same line; not aware on the behavior of mapping everything same.